# Code to move multiple rows and columns into singular row with multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking for a piece of code that I can use to move data in Excel from multiple rows into one row based on it having the same id in column 1. See example data below:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
11111   Axx/111     
11111           Bxx/111 
11111                   Cxx/000
22222   Axx/112     
22222           Bxx/444 
22222                   Cxx/111
33333   Axx/113     
33333           Bxx/555 
33333                   Cxx/222
44444   Axx/114     
44444           Bxx/666 
44444                   Cxx/333
55555   Axx/115     
55555           Bxx/777 
55555                   Cxx/444
```

Where the reference in column 1 is the same for multiple rows I want to move the data from the multiple columns, keep it in columns but have it all referenced in 1 row. So instead of  this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
11111   Axx/111     
11111           Bxx/111 
11111                   Cxx/000
```

I get this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
11111   Axx/111 Bxx/111 Cxx/000
11111           
11111
```

or this:

```
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
11111   Axx/111 Bxx/111 Cxx/000
11111   Axx/111 Bxx/111 Cxx/000
11111   Axx/111 Bxx/111 Cxx/000
```

Please help!

Comment: so what have you tried? have tried to record a macro?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to sum and you are certain there is only 1 element to retrieve per column you can use `VLOOKUP`. Create another sheet with your keys on the left. You can use `Data > Delete duplicates` to get only unique keys. Then you use a formula similar to this:

In Column 2:
`=VLOOKUP($A2, A:D, 2, 0)`

In Column 3:
`=VLOOKUP($A2, A:D, 3, 0)`

In Column 2:
`=VLOOKUP($A2, A:D, 4, 0)`

Comment: Of course! Why didnt I think of that, thank you I think I had gotten lost in the detail.

Comment: And yes, when you get focused too long on a problem I've found that most of the time it's because you are overthinking it.